# Mathematica provides complicated forms of solutions

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions

I always wonder how can one find solutions in Mathematica in a simple form. When I find answers to an equation, the output is always in a messy form. For example below is the answer for a parameter I got when I run my code:

```
-((0.09428090415820634`  Sqrt[-1 + 
  15 e ro] (alpha ro ((0.` + 
        1.119744`*^9 I) - (0.` + 3.919104`*^10 I) e ro + (0.` + 
         4.19904`*^11 I) e^2 ro^2 - (0.` + 
         1.259712`*^12 I) e^3 ro^3) + 
   dr ((0.` - 
        8.0621568`*^11 I) + (0.` + 
         3.22486272`*^13 I) e ro - (0.` + 
         4.43418624`*^14 I) e^2 ro^2 + (0.` + 
         2.41864704`*^15 I) e^3 ro^3 - (0.` + 
         4.5349632`*^15 I) e^4 ro^4)) v Cos[
  t])/(alpha ro (-298598.40000000026` + 1.1943936`*^7 e ro - 
    1.6422912`*^8 e^2 ro^2 + 8.957952`*^8 e^3 ro^3 - 
    1.679616`*^9 e^4 ro^4) + 
 dr (2.14990848`*^8 - 9.674588159999992`*^9 e ro + 
    1.61243136`*^11 e^2 ro^2 - 1.236197376`*^12 e^3 ro^3 + 
    4.43418624`*^12 e^4 ro^4 - 6.0466176`*^12 e^5 ro^5)))
```

I'm sure that it could be shown in more simple way. for example multiplication of some terms with exponents. Is there any way to change the solution in this form? I have tried Simplify but it doesn't change the form of the solution. Any answer which could show the solution in more simple way is highly approcated.
*By more simple I mean more compact form. for example I prefer the solution (x+a)^3+(x+b)^3 other than 2 x^3 + 3x^2 a + 3x^2 b+....

I have applied the procedure in the answer to below expression:

```
ex = ((0.` + 11.785113019775793` I) dr  Sqrt[-1.` + 
 15.` e ro] (h^2 (0.004629629629629629` h + 
     0.000462962962962963` alpha ro) + 
  dr h (h (0.3472222222222222` - 1.0416666666666667` e ro) + 
     alpha ro (0.034722222222222224` - 
        0.10416666666666667` e ro)) + 
  dr^2 (alpha ro (0.2` + 1.` e ro) + h (2.` + 10.` e ro))) v Cos[
 t])/(dr^2 h (-0.0074074074074074086` h - 
   0.0005555555555555556` alpha ro) + 
h^3 (-4.822530864197532`*^-6 h - 
   4.018775720164609`*^-7 alpha ro) + 
dr h^2 (alpha ro (-0.00003858024691358025` + 
      0.00011574074074074075` e ro) + 
   h (-0.00048225308641975306` + 0.0014467592592592592` e ro)) + 
dr^3 (alpha ro (0.013333333333333329` - 
      0.26666666666666666` e ro + 1.` e^2 ro^2) + 
   h (0.2` - 4.` e ro + 15.` e^2 ro^2)))
```

where

```
h= 30 dr (6 e ro - 1.2 + 0.8 Sqrt[3 - 30 e ro]);
```

I could change ex to

```
((0. + 500. I) v (-3. + X) Sqrt[1 - X^2] (3. + 38. X - 52. X^2 + 10. X^3 + 1. X^4 + alpha ro (-0.0166667 - 0.233333 X - 0.0166667 X^2)) Cos[t])/((-1. + X) (9. - 6. X - 113. X^2 + 140. X^3 - 25. X^4 - 6. X^5 + 1. X^6 + alpha ro (-0.0625 - 0.15 X + 0.475 X^2 + 0.0166667 X^3 - 0.0125 X^4)))
```

by below change

```
e -> (3 - X^2)/(30 ro)
```

But after that, Simplify can not make it simpler. Could anyone guess what is the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you regard as "simple". Have you tried `Expand`? Is that "simple"? If `e, ro, dr` etc. are **real**, then how about `ComplexExpand`?

Comment: Yes they are real. By more simple I mean more compact form. forexample one can write (x+a)^3+ (x+b)^3 in a more complicated form: 2 x^3 + 3 a x^2 +... @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: Can you show how you would like the expression above to look when it is at its most simple? Or a slightly smaller, but not trivial example?

Comment: ComplexExpand and Expand do a vice-versa! they made solution more complicated(more terms apear when using them) @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: Forexample maybe the numerator and denominator could be written in the form of sum of (constant + e ro)^n @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: That's a big maybe! The expression you have shown is already factored in terms of `dr` and `alpha`, as much as seems possible at a first glance. And looking at the factor next to `alpha ro` in the numerator, we can try `SolveAlways[
 1.119744`*^9 - 3.919104`*^10 e ro + 4.19904`*^11 e^2 ro^2 - 
   1.259712`*^12 e^3 ro^3 == (const - e ro)^3, {e, ro}]`, but this returns `{}`, meaning that there is no solution of this form. So your "maybe" is a "no" at least for that factor.

Comment: The expression can be written as `(100/Sqrt[2]) I v Sqrt[15 e ro - 1] Cos[t]/(0.2 - e ro) ` so the question seems reasonable

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How did you understand it?@SimonWoods

Comment: I mean, how did you guess the simple form?@SimonWoods

Comment: please note Simon's comment @MariusLadegårdMeyer

Comment: How can I do in the same way as you did? I have 5 complicated solutions and I want to simplify them as you did. Could you pease let me know how did you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes `Simplify` works like magic, but other times you need to apply a bit of mathematical intuition to help it. These are the steps I took to find a simpler expression.

First notice that `e` and `ro` always appear together, so put the expression in terms of `x = e ro`

```
expr /. e -> x/ro

(* -((0.0942809 v Sqrt[-1 + 
      15 x] (alpha ro ((0. + 
            1.11974*10^9 I) - (0. + 3.9191*10^10 I) x + (0. + 
             4.19904*10^11 I) x^2 - (0. + 1.25971*10^12 I) x^3) + 
       dr ((0. - 
            8.06216*10^11 I) + (0. + 3.22486*10^13 I) x - (0. + 
             4.43419*10^14 I) x^2 + (0. + 
             2.41865*10^15 I) x^3 - (0. + 4.53496*10^15 I) x^4)) Cos[
      t])/(alpha ro (-298598. + 1.19439*10^7 x - 1.64229*10^8 x^2 + 
        8.95795*10^8 x^3 - 1.67962*10^9 x^4) + 
     dr (2.14991*10^8 - 9.67459*10^9 x + 1.61243*10^11 x^2 - 
        1.2362*10^12 x^3 + 4.43419*10^12 x^4 - 6.04662*10^12 x^5))) *)
```

There are several polynomials in `x` with awkward machine precision coefficients. Try pulling out an overall numerical factor from those. I also wrap the numerical factors in `Hold` to stop everything multiplying out again.

```
% /. Plus[n_?NumberQ, m__] :> Hold[n] Rationalize@Expand[(n + m)/n]

(* -((0.0942809 v Cos[
      t] Sqrt[(1 - 
        15 x) Hold[-1]] (alpha ro (1 - 35 x + 375 x^2 - 
          1125 x^3) Hold[0. + 1.11974*10^9 I] + 
       dr (1 - 40 x + 550 x^2 - 3000 x^3 + 5625 x^4) Hold[
         0. - 8.06216*10^11 I]))/(alpha ro (1 - 40 x + 550 x^2 - 
        3000 x^3 + 5625 x^4) Hold[-298598.] + 
     dr (1 - 45 x + 750 x^2 - 5750 x^3 + 20625 x^4 - 28125 x^5) Hold[
       2.14991*10^8])) *)
```

Okay, that was successful - the polynomials are revealed to have nice integer coefficients. Perhaps `Simplify` can do something useful now. (I also release the held numbers after simplifying).

```
ReleaseHold[Simplify[%]]

(* (0.0188562 v Sqrt[-1 + 
    15 x] ((0. - 2.23949*10^8 I) alpha ro - (0. + 
        8.06216*10^11 I) dr (-0.2 + 1. x)) Cos[
    t])/((-0.2 + 1. x) (59719.7 alpha ro + 
     2.14991*10^8 dr (-0.2 + 1. x))) *)
```

It's getting better. Next notice that `-0.2 + 1. x` appears in several places, so replace that with `y` and try simplifying again.

```
Simplify[% /. {(-0.2` + 1.` x) -> y}]

(* -(((0. + 70.7107 I) v Sqrt[-1 + 
   15 x] (0.000277778 alpha ro + 1. dr y) Cos[t])/(
 y (0.000277778 alpha ro + 1. dr y))) *)
```

At this point I just manually cancelled the bracketed term from the top and bottom, and put `x` and `y` back in terms of `e` and `ro`. Oh, and recognised that 70.7107 is 100/Sqrt[2].

```
expr2 = (100/Sqrt[2]) I v Sqrt[15 e ro - 1] Cos[t]/(0.2 - e ro)
```

Finally I chucked in a few test parameters to make sure that `expr` and `expr2` gave the same result.

The same thing might work for your other expressions, it depends how similar they are. Note that a key part was being able to express the polynomials with exact integer coefficients (using `Rationalize`) so that `Simplify` could divide them. If possible you could try redoing the original calculation with rationals in place of machine precision values, you might find you get a result which `Simplify` can process directly.

Comment: It was the best answer I have ever seen on this site. Thank you very much.

Comment: I used this procedure for the solution I added to the question, but it was not successful to make it simpler. Could you please give me some guide about this case?

Comment: @saralolisaraloli, I had a look at the second case but I can't see any way to get a similar compact expression, if one exists.

Comment: Could you please look at my new question? Do you have any ideas? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/145488/problem-of-complicated-solutions-simplify-doesnt-work